# What is the meaning of "can u guess where my thumb is?"

Tags: meaning, idioms

[image]

I cannot understand the context of this sentence
Is it an idiom? 
Or just guess the place of his thumb
I think it has sexual meaning.

Answer (score 2):

There's an expression

> sitting (or standing) around with your thumb up your ass

which means doing something useless.  And deliberately so, since you could hardly do something so awkward and uncomfortable by accident.

The actor Ryan Reynolds jokes (on Conan O'Briens talk show) that he's promoting a sex tape involving himself and the cast of *Fox and Friends*, one of the right-wing propaganda shows on the Fox Network. He's calling the tape *Can You Guess Where My Thumb Is?*, a reference to the expression above. The implication is that you might expect a titillating, X-rated offering, but that wouldn't be the case because instead the the cast of *F&F* would be doing the useless stuff that (in Reynold's opinion) they usually do.

Comment: I'll drive by with an upvote. I think your explanation makes excellent sense. Er, thumbs up.

Comment: @Rob_Ster *Er, thumbs up* I saw what you did there. Touché. Thanks for the upvote. I hasten to add that my comment was meant neither to troll for upvotes nor to discourage downvotes. It's the lack of explanation for a downvote that annoys me. It leaves the impression that the answer is wrong (or at least lacking). If that's so, I have no opportunity to correct things; if that's not so, it may lead the OP to distrust a reliable response.